# How to skip the Superset signin page

Tags: apache-superset

I have integrated Superset with auth0.

as per my requirement, I don't need the default superset login page:

[image: Please click to view the initial Logon page]

I need to skip the above login page; I have to use Auth0 sign page as below,

[image: Click here to view Auth0 Login Page]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use custom login page you should implement custom Superset security manager which will solve the problem.

At first, you should create new file, e.g. `my_security_manager.py`. Put these lines into it:

```
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager

class MySecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):        
    def __init__(self, appbuilder):
        super(MySecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
```

Secondly, you should let Superset know that you want to use your brand new security manager. To do so, add these lines to your Superset configuration file (`superset_config.py`):

```
from my_security_manager import MySecurityManager
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = MySecurityManager
```

Then you can override **authdbview** property of MySecurityManager class with your custom view and show custom login page.

Comment: Thank you, Have implemented as you suggested. Now I am able Login and Logout successfully.

Comment: @Sathish I have a similar requirement. Would you be able to provide sample code for implementation of security manager you implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If don't care about who's gonna login or log out,

dashboards. Explicit grant on specific datasets is still required.
PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE: Optional[str] = "Enter Role Type access you need to given public users gamma/beta/admin"

setting in a superset config.py file from location .\lib\python3.8\site-packages\superset

Comment: note:`need to re-run the init user (if already run)`